# How to separate /etc/my.cnf for different mysql versions

Tags: mysql, config, percona

I want to be able to have different mysql/percona servers installed on same server.

However only one of them will be active until I decide to deactivate it and activate another.

Is there easy way to put `/etc/my.cnf` inside mysql data directory instead of `/etc`?
PHP using similar approach - ini file is inside php directory and /etc/php.ini is a symlink.

I am thinking about global /etc/my.cnf with single like `!!includedir /xxxx/yyyy/$version`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can installed different version on same node with different data directive. To run same,you need to run mysql server with path of config file like below:

> FULL_PATH/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=FULL_PATH/my.cnf &